# How to eliminate missing data

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gNe5.png)I want to eliminate the missing value from the column ret and dlret within the file named crsp_data. Here is my code:

```
crsp_data_ret=crsp_data['ret'].dropna()
crsp_data_dlret=crsp_data['dlret'].dropna()
crsp_data['retadj']=(1+crsp_data['ret'])*(1+crsp_data['dlret'])-1
```

### But it gives me the follwing error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3062             try:
-> 3063                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3064             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'dlret'
```

Anyone could help me by indicating anywhere I did wrongly? 
I appreciate your help!

[There are NANs in ret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXE5A.png)

---

```
crsp_data['retadj']=(1+crsp_data['ret'])*(1+crsp_data['dlret_x'])-1
crsp_data_retadj=crsp_data.dropna(subset=['retadj'])
crsp_data['retadj'].head(50)
```

0          NaN
1    -0.248538
2     0.428202
3    -0.086215
4    -0.125488
5     0.030425
6    -0.203367
7    -0.611781
8    -0.051796
9    -0.328013
10    0.065550
11   -0.413984
12   -0.343434
13    0.052632
14   -0.420102
15   -0.089628
16   -0.036559
17         NaN
18         NaN
19    0.039082
20    0.480844
21    0.025029
22    0.056209
23   -0.013069
24   -0.060239
25         NaN
26    0.033846
27         NaN
28    0.121294
29    0.185520
30   -0.035714
31         NaN

Comment: The error is saying you do not have a column called `'dlret'`

Comment: I do and I have a column called dlret. should I remove the corma? could you please have a look at the answer I posted just now to this question. I uploaded the screenshot of the excel

Comment: Can you show what this prints `crsp_data.columns.values` ?

Comment: 'permno' 'date' 'SHRCD' 'EXCHCD' 'ret' 'end_date' 'dlret_x' 'dlsdt'
 'dlret_y' 'dlstdt' .

Comment: This is what it showed. And I changed my code to eliminate dlret_x. and it's working now. But I don't understand, I did not let python generate dlret_x and dlret_y for me, why it is automatically there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is:

```
crsp_data_ret=crsp_data['ret']
crsp_data_dlret=crsp_data['dlret']
```

return `Series`, so imposible select later, [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) is used:

```
crsp_data_ret=crsp_data['ret'].dropna()
crsp_data_dlret=crsp_data['dlret'].dropna()
```

Solution is remove `['ret']` and `['dlret']`:

```
crsp_data['retadj']=(1+crsp_data)*(1+crsp_data)-1
```

---

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), so `DataFrame`s are returned:

```
crsp_data_ret=crsp_data.dropna(subset=['ret'])
crsp_data_dlret=crsp_data.dropna(subset=['dlret'])


crsp_data['retadj']=(1+crsp_data['ret'])*(1+crsp_data['dlret'])-1
```

EDIT:

If need ignore `NaN`s one possible solution is use [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`, then get:

```
crsp_data = pd.DataFrame({'ret':[1,2,'C', 5, np.nan],
                   'dlret':[10, np.nan, 7, 1, np.nan]})

crsp_data['ret'] = pd.to_numeric(crsp_data['ret'], errors='coerce')

crsp_data['retadj1']=(1+crsp_data['ret'])*(1+crsp_data['dlret'])-1

crsp_data['retadj2']= crsp_data['ret'].add(1, fill_value=0).mul(crsp_data['dlret'].add(1, fill_value=0)).sub(1)
print (crsp_data)

   ret  dlret  retadj1  retadj2
0  1.0   10.0     21.0     21.0
1  2.0    NaN      NaN      2.0
2  NaN    7.0      NaN      7.0
3  5.0    1.0     11.0     11.0
4  NaN    NaN      NaN      0.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print (crsp_data['ret'].add(1, fill_value=0))
0    2.0
1    3.0
2    1.0
3    6.0
4    1.0
Name: ret, dtype: float64

print (crsp_data['dlret'].add(1, fill_value=0).sub(1))
0    10.0
1     0.0
2     7.0
3     1.0
4     0.0
Name: dlret, dtype: float64
```